# Zend Form Displays Htmlentities instead of accents when populated

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, populate, html-entities

couldn't find a solution for this weird problem.

I've got a Zend_Form that is populated with the data from a Mysql database.
I've got everything setup for UTF-8

resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8" and $this->_view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');

The result set I get from the db is OK, with the accents and all, but when I try to populate the form it displays for example &aacute instead of á.
I tried to decode the result set using htmlspecialchars_decode and html_entity_decode but still, when I populate the form it shows html entities.
I have also tried to use the UTF8 encode after decoding the html but than the result is even worse, with weird characters and also htmlentities.

Does anyone have any idea to help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to disable the escaping, you can do it directly on the element:

```
$element->setAttrib("escape", false);
```

If you need some Filters you have to configure the encoding, here an example for the one mentioned in the comment:

```
$enc = array('quotestyle' => ENT_QUOTES, 'charset' => 'UTF-8');
$filter = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities($enc));
$element->addFilter($filter);
```

Filters like StringToLower are implementing an method called "setEncoding();"

Comment: do you use any kind of filters?

Comment: You got it  ArneRie. I was using HtmlEntities filter, I just remove it worked! I thought that filter were applied when validating the form and not when populating it. so now I can't filter htmlentities when validating?  Anyway thank you so much for your help!

Comment: ArneRie sorry to bother you again about this issue, but I can't find a solution. I tried to apply the Html filter as you said but than the first problem comes back, the form displays htmlentities. If the filter is disabled fine, but I don't want to disable it for security. I read all Zend_Filter Class docs but couldn't find a way to implement the filter without displaying the htmlentities, if you know a way please help me. Thanks

Comment: iam not sure why you need this filter? Try it with StripTags?

Comment: right again, I was confusing htmlentities with striptags... Thanks again ArneRie. all the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the "sanitized" HTML entities, use StripTags filter instead. StripTags delete the HTML and PHP tags while HtmlEntities encode them.

Try this:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags();
```

instead of:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities()
```

Comment: :-) Sorry, I had not seen the hidden comments.